# Unable to call an existing method from underscoreJS-rendered template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a small Backbone / Underscore app. I have rendered one template, along with rendering a method call "onclick" of a button (which works smoothly, btw). The function which is called, renders another template, which has another method call "onclick" of a button.

- #showTransportsTemplate: first template / has a "transport" model passed to it
- bookTicket(tid): first function / uses "tid" to fetch the associated transport model from the collection AND sets them into a "booking model" which is passed on to the second template
- #confirmBookingTemplate: second template

  - confirmBooking() : second method (which exists but is not being recognized and hence not called)

Here is the code:

related part of app.js:

```
function bookTicket(tid)
{
    alert("received tid: "+tid);
    var transport = transportList.findWhere({id:tid});
    console.log(transport);



    var newBooking = new Booking();
    newBooking.set('id',"b"+getBookingId());
    newBooking.set('mode',transport.get('mode'));
    newBooking.set('source',transport.get('source'));
    newBooking.set('destination',transport.get('destination'));
    newBooking.set('date',transport.get('date'));
    newBooking.set('class',transport.get('class'));
    newBooking.set('rate',transport.get('rate'));

    var confirmBookingTemplate = _.template($('#confirmBookingTemplate').html(), {booking: newBooking});
               alert(confirmBookingTemplate); // for testing purposes


                $(confirmBooking.el).show();
                 $(confirmBooking.el).html(confirmBookingTemplate);                 
}

function confirmBooking()
{
    alert("confirmBooking"); // no further code written coz this function is not getting called
}
```

The two templates:

```
<script type="text/template" id="showTransportsTemplate">

            <table border="1">

                <tr>

                <th> Source </th>
                <th> Destination </th>
                <th> Date Available </th>
                <th> Class </th>
                <th> Rate </th>
                <th> Book </th>
                </tr>



                <% _.each(selTransports, function (transport) {  

                    var myid= transport.get("id");

                %>

                <tr>

                        <td align="center"> <%= transport.get("source") %> </td>
                        <td align="center"> <%= transport.get("destination") %> </td>
                        <td align="center"> <%= transport.get("date") %> </td>
                        <td align="center"> <%= transport.get("class") %> </td>
                        <td align="center"> <%= transport.get("rate") %> </td>
                        <td> <input type="button" onclick="bookTicket('<%= myid %>')" value="Book"> 
                         </input>
                        </td>
                        <td> <%= myid %> </td>
                    </tr>
                  <%
                        });

                    %>

            </table>
        </script>

        <script type="text/template" id="confirmBookingTemplate">
             <br /><br />
            <h3> Booking Details </h3>

            <br />

            <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
            <td> <b> Customer Name: </b> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="cname" /> </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> 

                    <%
                    var travel;
                        if (booking.get("mode") === "F") travel = "Flight"
                        else if (booking.get("mode") === "B") travel = "Bus"
                        else if (booking.get("mode") === "T") travel = "Train"
                    %>

                    <b><%= travel %></b> from <b><%=booking.get("source")%></b> to <b><%=booking.get("destination")%></b>
                   in <b><%=booking.get("class")%></b> class on <b><%=booking.get("date")%></b> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <b> Cost per ticket: </b> </td>
            <td> Rs. <%= booking.get("rate") %> </td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <td> <b> No. of Adults: </b> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="adults" /> </td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <td> <b> No. of  Children: </b> </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="children" /> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td> <b> Total Amount: </b> </td>
            <td> <output  id="totalAmount"> </output> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"> 

                <input type="button" value="Book Ticket" id="confirm" onclick="confirmBooking()">
                </td>

            </tr>
    </table>
        </script>
```

I tried with Chrome, the error was "object is not a function". Firebug says: "confirmBooking()" is not a function, BUT IT ALREADY EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore's template function uses a javascript [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) block when evaluating templates, which means that any "unqualified names" are assumed to be part of the data object passed-in to the [`template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) method. In this case, `confirmBooking` is not part of that object, and so the template is not able to find it.

If you truly wish to invoke a global function from within your template (and you should think twice about defining functions in the global namespace), then you may do so by explicitly referencing the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object, like so:

```
window.someGlobalFunction = function() {
    return "It worked!";   
}

<script type="text/template" id="template">
    <%= window.someGlobalFunction() %>
</script>
```

A functioning example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/pqjtR/

Comment: Worked! but not with the window object. I create my own temp global object and attached my function to it. Thanks :-)